# internet explorer margin css hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer

im trying to line up two divs next to each other. i managed to hack the CSS for firefox and chrome but having problems with internet explorer. I have looked on here and google found a few but still having problems.

heres the website

http://colmandesigns.123abc.co.nz/dev/brittens/index.html

heres my css

http://codepad.org/Wohvhj3h

any help would be great

thanks

Comment: Really? compared to other browsers to me its not lined up with each image.

Comment: I can see problem in IE8, staffimages and stafftex are not aligned in IE, right? I recommend you to avoid structure like this. In your page, you've aligned stuffimages (all images) on left side, and then stufftext on right side. Instead of that, better solution is to create one div, put image and text for that image in it, and repeat that for each image and text for image.

Comment: Thanks Miljan Puzovic Will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is linked with the way you space the elements. To align the elements using this structure you'll have to delete all **<br>** tags which separates the anchors with images (inside 'staffimages') and use CSS margins.

```
    <div class="staffimages">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="images/staff.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="Johnny" border="0">
    </a>
    <br> -- delete this
    <br> -- also delete this (and so on)
```

Also, I recommend you don't use browser specific CSS hacks unless there is no other way to solve the issues.

Below you can see a CSS snippet to use with your HTML file.

```
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    body                            {margin: 0 auto;}
    
    .container                        {margin:0 auto; width:1000px; height:950px; background-image:url(images/container.png);}
    
    #head_back {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 16px;
    width:700px;
    right:700px;
    height: 126px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image:url(images/bgbg.png);
    }
    
    /* HEADER */
    
    .header                            {width:982px; height:370px; margin-left:9px; background-image:url(images/header.jpg);}
    .navibg                            {background-image:url(images/navibg.png); width: 983px; height:56px;}
    .logo                            {margin-top:-40px;}
    
    /* CONTENT TITLES */
    
    #welcome                        {width:89px; height:22px; padding-left:50px; padding-top:30px; float:left;}
    #services                        {width:89px; height:22px; margin-left:-90px; padding-top:250px; float:left;}
    #contactus                        {width:89px; height:22px; padding-left:50px; padding-top:30px; float:left;}
    #makinglifeeasy                    {width:89px; height:22px; padding-left:30px; padding-top:30px; float:left;}
    .seperator                        {width:300px; float:right; padding-top:30px; padding-right:90px;}
    #team { position: relative; margin-top: 30px; height: 19px; width: 78px; float: right; margin-right: -105px; }
    
    /* NAVIGATION */
    
    .navi                            {float:right; padding-right:50px; padding-top:3px;}
    
    /* CONTENT */
    
    .welcomecolumn                    {width:500px; height:auto; float:left; padding-left:6px; padding-top:5px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; text-align:justify; color:#505050; line-height:150%;}
    .servicescolumn                    {width:500px; height:auto; float:left; padding-left:6px; padding-top:5px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; text-align:justify; color:#505050; line-height:150%;}
    
    .list1                            {float:left; margin-left:-20px;}
    .list2                            {float:right; padding-right:200px;}
    
    /* FOOTER */
    
    .footer                            {background-image:url(images/footer.png); width:982px; height:65px; margin-left:9px; margin-top:460px;  color:#505050}
    .footernavi                        {font-size:9px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; float:right; padding-right:60px; padding-top:27px;}
    .footernavidetails                {font-size:10px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; float:left; padding-left:308px; padding-top:27px; color:#FFFFFF; }
    .footertext                        {padding-left:40px; font-size:10px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:110px; padding-bottom:5px; color:#aeaeae; text-align:center}
    
    /* TEAM */
    
    .staffimages {
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        margin-left:12px;
        margin-top:15px;
    }
    
    .staffimages a {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .stafftext1, .stafftext2, .stafftext3, .stafftext4, .stafftext5 {
        width:150px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:80px;
        color:#505050;
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:10px;
        text-align:justify;
        position:absolute;
    }
    
    .stafftext1    {
        top:30px;
    }
    
    .stafftext2    {
        top:100px;
    }
    
    .stafftext3    {
        top:170px;
    }
    
    .stafftext4    {
        top:242px;
    }
    
    .stafftext5 {
        top:311px;
    }
    
    /* READ MORE */
    
    #readmore, #readmore2, #readmore3, #readmore4, #readmore5 {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
    
    #readmore {
        top: 66px;
    }
    
    #readmore2 {
        top: 135px;
    }
    
    #readmore3 {
        top: 204px;
    }
    
    #readmore4 {
        top: 275px;
    }
    
    #readmore5 {
        top: 345px;
    }
        
        .contactdetails
            {font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; width:400px; padding-left:8px; line-height:40%; color:#626262}
            
        .main    {color:#626262}
        
        /* GOOGLE */
    
    .google                    {
        width:300px;
        height:305px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:8px;
        margin-top:12px;
        margin-bottom:20px;}    
    /* LINKS */
    
    a.colman:link { color:#aeaeae; text-decoration:none}      /* unvisited link */
    a.colman:visited { color:#aeaeae; text-decoration:none}  /* visited link */
    a.colman:hover {color:#0c3976; text-decoration:none}  /* mouse over link */
    a.colman:active { color:#aeaeae; text-decoration:none}  /* selected link */
    
    a.footerlinks:link { color:#FFFFFF;}      /* unvisited link */
    a.footerlinks:visited { color:#FFFFFF;}  /* visited link */
    a.footerlinks:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* mouse over link */
    a.footerlines:active { color:#FFFFFF;}  /* selected link */
```